# Dart, what is the "where" keyword

Tags: flutter, dart

I've seen the occasional list.where() code on stackoverflow.

So I'm trying to figure this out.

How is it different from .map()?

Where can I read the documentation to learn in detail about this?
(firstWhere, startWith ... etc very complex queries with => keywords)

Comment: here is the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable-class.html)

Comment: @Jabbar yah..  I actually have seen that documentation once but it is too short and less example so.. hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the methods workings in example:

```dart
final list = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// List.where is used to filter out element based on a condition
list.where((element) => element.isOdd); // [1, 3]

// List.map allows you to map each value to a new one (not necessarily of the same type)
list.map((element) => 2*element); // [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

#### Where to read this information

One of the best thing of dart (and flutter) is its source code documentation. In most code editors, you can ctrl+click on a method to see the documentation. From there you can learn what it does and there are sometimes example.

Another great place is StackOverflow of course, since those question are asked over and over, especially basic ones like this which are often the same across different languages.

Comment: So then where is basically 'for' statement.. it is same isn't it? Like returning value when the condition value you are looking for in the for statement is found. I don't know which one is better for performance but the internal algorithm seems to be the same

Comment: No a `for` statement allows you to iterate through the list not filter it. Try implementing `for` yourself, imitating me `where` here, you should see the difference.

Comment: you can add a "custom filter statement" inside for loop statements so it can be same. I think "where"is like the sugar syntax I guess

Answer (score 1):

you can read it from [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable-class.html)

the difference between [where](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) and [map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) is basically this, `where` return a new list "`iterable`" with only the elements that satisfies the passed test, and `map` return also a new list (but with the same length), each element is mapped with the passed function to different value (wether the same type or a completely different type)